# Vue.js - How to insert dollar$ sign into main index.html file

Tags: vue.js

I have the main `index.html` of my application.

When I try to build it, I get an **error**:

```
ERROR  Build failed with errors.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! axeleron@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

This error appears because there is a dollar **$** sign in my **index.html** file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="app"></div>

    <input value="${name}"/>

    </body>
</html>
```

The question is: how to make sure that the **error** does not occur?

Comment: The question is incorrect. The problem is not dollar sign but `${name}`, you didn't explain why it's needed. It is in conflict the syntax for Lodash templates which is used in public html files. It fails when it tries to interpolate `name`.

Comment: If I remove the dollar $ sign, then there is no problem. That's why I said that the problem is in the dollar sign. I think the point is clear. That's the question. How to solve this problem?

Comment: This is necessary in order to correctly use the freemarker template engine.

Comment: I use the freemarker template engine in conjunction with spring

Comment: Please, update the question with this info. The problem is not dollar sign but that you want to use it exactly like `${name}` string. You wouldn't have this problem with $ alone either

Comment: Please, add vue-cli tag as this is Vue CLI question, it wouldn't happen for Vue alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not dollar sign but the exact `${name}` string that follows ES template literal syntax. Vue CLI uses HtmlWebpackPlugin to process index.html, which uses Lodash `template` to interpolate environment variables in HTML templates. `_.template` supports ES template literal syntax, tries to interpolate `${name}` and fails because no `name` was provided.

This behaviour is not directly configurable in Vue CLI, in order for `template` to not use ES template syntax, `_.templateSettings.interpolate` regex need to be changed. This needs to be done in vue.config.js on the exact `lodash` package copy that HtmlWebpackPlugin uses, as there can be multiple package copies.

A more simple way to prevent it from being processed is to separate the string, so it would interpolate to `${name}`:

```
<input value="${'$'}{name}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't clear about what you're trying to say but i can help with this question,
**"Question: how to insert these parameters into the main index.html of the application?"**

May be you can use **java script** and then with the help of that you can add parameters into **"index.main"** file in any input field or any other tag.

```js
var TxtEle = document.getElementById('Txt');
var BtnEle = document.getElementById('Btn');

console.log(Txt);

BtnEle.addEventListener('click',() => {
  TxtEle.name = TxtEle.value;
});

console.log(Txt);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>
  Example...
  </title>
</head>

<center>
  <p>
  Add Name Parameter...
  </p>
<input type="txt" id="Txt">
<input type="submit" id="Btn">
</center>

</html>
```

Comment: It won't work. I have corrected the question.